# Problema em C ao ler arquivo e gravar em vetores/matrizes

Tags: c

Estou com problema ao ler dados de um arquivo e gravá-los em um vetor e matriz. Não consigo dar o `printf` para testá-los. Portanto não tenho certeza se o código está correto. O arquivo tem nome de alunos e suas matrículas respectivamente.

```c
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include string.h
#define TOT 5

int le_alunos(char nome_al[], int matricula_al[][TOT+1]){

    int i=0, c;
    FILE *alunos;



    alunos = fopen("ALUNOS.TXT","r");
    if(alunos == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo \"ALUNOS.TXT\" ");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = fscanf(alunos,"%[^\n] %d", &nome_al[i], matricula_al[i]);
    while(c==2){
        i++;

        printf("Nome:%s...................Matricula:%d", nome_al[i],matricula_al[i]);
    }   

    fclose(alunos);
    return i;
}

int main(void){

    int i;
    char nome_al[81];
    int matricula_al[2][TOT+1];
    int papagaio;

    papagaio = le_alunos(nome_al,matricula_al,i);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não consegui identificar na sua explicação qual o problema que você está tendo. Dê mais detalhes do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Você deve [edit] sua pergunta para colocar novas informações e não responder a ela, a não ser que já tenha resolvido o problema e deseja postar o solução achada para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Bom eu tenho um arquivo .txt que possui nome de alunos e suas matriculas. Eu quero ler esse arquivo e guardar os nomes em uma matriz, e as matriculas em um vetor. Só que coloquei esse printf dentro do while para que ele fosse me informando o que ele já está guardando. Só que ao rodar o programa ele não aparece nada no console... Então não sei se o programa está entrando dentro do while ou não. fiz alguns testes e não consegui chegar a nenhuma conclusão...

Answer (score 2):

Inclua isso e vê se te ajuda amigo! =)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char url[]="pontos.txt";
FILE *arq;
arq = fopen(url, "a"); 

fprintf(arq,"Jogo %2d  deu %2d pontos\n", x , pontos);
```

É preciso trabalhar com os ponteiros.

Um endereço `char url[]=" ";`, que será - `char url[]="pontos.txt";`
Um ponteiro tipo `FILE arq`, que será - `FILE *arq;`
E abrir o arquivo com o ponteiro apontando para a `url[]` através da função `fopen`,
que será - `arq = fopen(url, "a");`.

Agora é só gravar:

```
fprintf(arq,"Jogo %2d  deu %2d pontos\n", x , pontos);
```