# Leitura de arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Preciso ler, de um arquivo, a quantidade de testes a ser feito e quais testes a serem feitos. O arquivo de entrada é o seguinte:

```
4            //Numero de testes a serem feitos
1 LINSIMP 3  //Primeiro(1) teste que verifica se a linha 3 é simples
2 LINPOL 3 1 //Segundo(2) teste que verifica se a linha 3 intercepta poligono 1
3 POLSIMP 1  //Terceiro(3) teste que verifica se o poligono 1 é simples
4 PTOPOL 1 1 //Quarto(4) teste que verifica se o ponto 1 está no poligono 1
```

A quantidade de testes(que são quatro) já foi implementado através da função:

```
int LeNumeroDeTestes(FILE *entrada)
{
    int numTestes;
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &numTestes);
    return numTestes;
}
```

Porém, estou tendo dificuldades para encontrar um jeito de ler o restante do arquivo de entrada. Cheguei a implementar o seguinte:

```
int i, LinhaTeste;
char Teste[10];
for(i = 0; i < numTestes; i++)
{
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &i);
    fscanf(entrada, "%s", Teste);
    if(i == 0)
    {
        fscanf(entrada, "%d", &LinhaTeste);
        printf("%d %s %d", i, Teste, LinhaTeste);
    }
}
```

Mas não parece uma solução muito boa. Além disso, apesar de não ocorrer erros na compilação, nada é impresso na tela. (Não cheguei a terminar os casos de i = 1, 2 e 3).

Gostaria de saber uma forma melhor de se ler esse arquivo.

Comment: Vc só qr exibir todo conteúdo dele na tela ou quer exibir um conteúdo especifico dele?

Comment: Eu queria exibir na tela apenas para saber se estou lendo corretamente, porque na verdade, não é necessário imprimir. O que será impresso, no exercício, é outro conteúdo.

Comment: Não estou entendendo o q vc qr. Poderia ser mais especifico em relação a sua dificuldade?

Comment: O que eu realmente preciso é apenas ler aquele arquivo de entrada que foi especificado acima. Porém, não sei se estou fazendo a leitura da maneira correta. A parte de impressão é apenas para saber se estou lendo os dados corretamente. A minha dúvida principal é: Como ler os dados de entrada de maneira correta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema em C ao ler arquivo e gravar em vetores/matrizes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39132/problema-em-c-ao-ler-arquivo-e-gravar-em-vetores-matrizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas é que no seu código você não está lendo até o final da linha. Os comentários, por exemplo, não estão sendo ignorados. Na função `LeNumeroDeTestes()` você pode colocar um `while` para avançar até o final da linha, da seguinte maneira:

```
int LeNumeroDeTestes(FILE *entrada)
{
    int numTestes;
    fscanf(entrada, "%d", &numTestes);
    while (fgetc(entrada) != '\n');
    return numTestes;
}
```

Para ler o restante do arquivo, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
int i, LinhaTeste;
char Teste[10];
for(i = 0; i < numTestes; i++)
{
    fscanf(entrada, "%d %s", &LinhaTeste, Teste); # Lê o número e o nome do teste (1ª e 2ª colunas)
    while (fgetc(entrada) != '\n'); # Avança até o fim da linha, ignorando o restante das informações
    printf("%d %s %d\n", i, Teste, LinhaTeste);
}
```

Além disso que foi feito, você provavelmente vai precisar interpretar os parâmetros que vêm depois do nome do teste. Então ao invés de simplesmente avançar até o final da linha você vai precisar de um laço que lê cada parâmetro até encontrar: ou o fim da linha; ou a marca de comentário, a partir da qual você avança até o fim da linha.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer a leitura do arquivo é obter todos os caracteres dele em um loop.

Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lerArquivo(FILE * arq)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getc(arq)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *arq = NULL;
    arq = fopen("arq.txt", "r");

    if (arq)
    {
        lerArquivo(arq);
        fclose(arq);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> 4            //Numero de testes a serem feitos
>   1 LINSIMP 3  //Primeiro(1) teste que verifica se a linha 3 é simples
>   2 LINPOL 3 1 //Segundo(2) teste que verifica se a linha 3 intercepta poligono 1
>   3 POLSIMP 1  //Terceiro(3) teste que verifica se o poligono 1 é simples
>   4 PTOPOL 1 1 //Quarto(4) teste que verifica se o ponto 1 está no poligono 1

A função `lerArquivo()` faz a leitura e exibição dos dados para você.